# how to trigger jenkins downstream job only both upstreams jobs successfully executed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, reverse, jenkins-job-builder, upstream-branch

I have created **Job A** which looks for upstream jobs **(Job B and Job C)** success result and triggers a shell script to verify a condition.

Once **Job B** and **Job C** executed successfully **Job A** executes downstream jobs **(Job D and Job E)**.

I have used `reverse` (to configure upstream jobs) and `downstream-ext` (to configure downstream jobs) plugins in **Job A** using JJB.

Issue I am facing here is: After Job B is executed successfully without waiting for Job C result. Job A should wait for both Job B and Job C and then execute based on the result.

Could you please help me how to configure this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Join Plugin, here is the documentation:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

This'd be easier if you convert your A job to a build flow  https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin?focusedCommentId=60917290 or even better it's successor Pipeline 2.0 https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/

(Groovy) Code in A would then be something like:

```
if (build('scenario-B-Job') && build('scenario-C-Job')) {
    build('scenario-E-Job')
    build('scenario-D-Job')
```

}
You can also parallelize (B,C and then D,E) to shorten overall execution times if you have enough slaves around.